# Returning value to another variable outside a block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Suppose I have this kind function with a block inside it:

```
-(BOOL)checkSomething
{
    server = [[Server alloc] initWith:privateVar];

    [server checkSomethingWithCompletion:^(BOOL success){
        //I want to return the value of success
    }];

}
```

How do I go about returning the value that I get from the completion block? I'm not able to set variable from outside the block inside it. I'm also not able to return the value directly from the block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `checkSomethingWithCompletion:` method is running synchronously, declare a `__block` variable before the block. You can then write to the variable from your block.

If your method is running asynchronously, `checkSomething` will return sooner than `checkSomethingWithCompletion` and therefore you cannot return anything from this block. In this case, you should use some asynchronous way to get the data, e.g. using notification, delegate or a callback method. The completion block could also be a parameter to your `checkSomething` method.

Comment: I prefer use callbacks like - (void)checkSomething:(void (^)(BOOL result))callback { /* ... */ }

Comment: of course, there would be no point in making a synchronous method called `checkSomethingWithCompletion:`, since whatever happens in "completion" can just be done after the method call

Comment: @Sulthan it would help to provide an example please.